# Background Music is still running if click on Home Screen in Android Emulator

Tags: android

I have a button which leads to open a Preference Screen, hence I have not released Media Player object in `onPause()`.

But this leads to problem of running background music when clicks on Home button in Android Emulator.

Comment: then what are you waiting for ?? stop it before move to other acitivity

Comment: I want background music to be running in Preference screen and not when click on Home Button.

Comment: remove it on Home button click ??

Answer (score 0):

take variable before oncreate

```
boolean pref_clicked=false;
```

onclick of button just write pref_clicked=true;

and

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(!pref_clicked)
       //pause your music player
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //pause your music player
}
```

Comment: only onPause() method is called while clicking on Home button, so I think it will not work....